# Is winston logging framework is truly Async

Tags: node.js, winston

I am developing a logging framework using winston in nodejs , I had check that winston using Async module , but I need to verify whether it is truly Async nature or not.

Please suggest.

Comment: upvoted - it is a good question, although poorly written

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I have no experience with Winston, other than I'm aware of it and its purpose. After a quick review of the [source on github](https://github.com/flatiron/winston/), I'd say that *no, winston is not truly async in all aspects*.

- It does `emit`, but `EventEmitter` is not async.
- Methods have an async-style signature (w/`callback`), but are not always async.

The [`Console` transport calls `callback` without a nextTick](https://github.com/flatiron/winston/blob/master/lib/winston/transports/console.js#L56-L89) - it has an async-style signature, but it is still within the same tick, i.e.:

```
Console.prototype.log = function (level, msg, meta, callback) {
  if (this.silent) {
    return callback(null, true);
  }
  //...
  if (level === 'error' || level === 'debug') {
    process.stderr.write(output + '\n');
  } else {
    process.stdout.write(output + '\n');
  }

  //
  // Emit the `logged` event immediately because the event loop
  // will not exit until `process.stdout` has drained anyway.
  //
  self.emit('logged');
  callback(null, true);
};
```

[`Logger` is similar to `Console`](https://github.com/flatiron/winston/blob/master/lib/winston/logger.js#L115-L210) as mentioned in previous in that it issues callbacks immediately w/o a `nextTick` (or some other real async op). It does use the [`async` module, but that is not asynchronous on all accounts either](https://github.com/caolan/async/blob/master/lib/async.js#L44-L51), i.e.:

```
  function cb(err) {
    if (callback) {
      if (err) return callback(err);
      callback(null, level, msg, meta);
    }
    callback = null;
    if (!err) {
      self.emit('logged', level, msg, meta);
    }
  }

  async.forEach(this._names, emit, cb);
```

I will give Winston that its [`File` transport is actually async, but only because `fs` is](https://github.com/flatiron/winston/blob/master/lib/winston/transports/file.js#L101-L156).

Don't forget that "console functions are synchronous when the destination is a terminal or a file" anyways.

Comment: lol, if everything is async, nothing would ever happen, because everything would be "returned in the future" :)  using event emitter is not a sign of non-async action. what matters is that the i/o is async.